# Using a VLOOKUP lookup_value that contains a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Using Excel I am using a VLOOKUP where the lookup_value contains a formula that generates the string that should be searched. The formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(MID(A2,2,5),Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```

All results come back with #N/A, yet if i substitute the MID() function with the value it generates the VLOOKUP functions fine.

Example data:

Sheet1

```
$#00001#
$#00002#
```

Sheet 2

```
00001 | Hello
00002 | World
```

Comment: Is the **00001** in sheet2 actually a **1** in a cell that has been formatted as `"00000"`(leading zeroes)? If so, you will need to convert the MID to a true number with `=VLOOKUP(--MID(A2,2,5),Sheet2!A:B,2,0)`. You cannot lookup text-that-looks-like-a-number in a column of true numbers regardless of how the true numbers are formatted for display.

Comment: Correct @Jeeped, problem solved.

Comment: Do you want to classify this as a typo or should I post an answer?

Comment: Put as answer, the anomaly of the leading zeros was in my example but the real scenario I was trying to solve did not have leading zeros it just had five digit numbers. So the answer isn't necessarily specific to there be leading zeros but to the general problem I was experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **00001** in sheet2 is actually a **1** in a cell that has been formatted as `"00000"` to display leading zeroes. This does not alter the raw underlying value of **1**. You will need to convert the MID result to a true number with a **double unary** like,

```
 =VLOOKUP(--MID(A2,2,5),Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```

You cannot lookup text-that-looks-like-a-number in a column of true numbers regardless of how the true numbers are formatted for display.

Tip: Unless you manually change the cell alignment, text is left-aligned by default; numbers are right-aligned by default. This is a quick visual check that can prove the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Jeeped's answer. however, looks like if $ was a literal, formula should actually contain

```
MID(A2,3,5)
```

as 00001 starts at position 3.

Formatting the column A in Sheet2 as Text is also a solution.

P.S. i am writing as answer since i was unable to comment on the question instead.